# Python: Unexpected result in a recursive function

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I've written a recursive function to gauge, e.g. list depth and for some reason it returns unexpected results.

I have two functions:
1. checks if the object is iterable
2. gauges the depth of the object, e.g. list

I think I'm missing something in the second function but I couldn't wrap my head around why exactly variable `n` when returned from `else` turns into a funny result.
I set `print` to see how `n` gets changed in every stage and it seemed working as expected but when returned from `else` it turns into a wrong number.

Here are two functions' code:

```
def isiterable(obj):
    '''
    takes in an obj and returns 1 if iterable or 0 if not
    strings are discarded as iterable
    :param obj: any object
    :return: int
    '''
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return 0
    else:
        try:
            iter(obj)
            return 1
        except TypeError as err:
            return 0
```

my second function is recursive where I'm experiencing problems

```
def get_depth(a, n=0):

    if isiterable(a):
        return n + f(a[0], n+1)

    else:
        return n
```

I've three examples:

```
a = [[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]]
b = [[1,2], [2,3]]
c = [2]
```

I'm expecting `get_depth` to return 3 for list `a`, 2 for list `b` and 1 for list `c`.

for some reason results for `a` get doubled and return 6. In `b` case it is 3 instead of 2.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `n` when you return from `get_depth`.

```
def get_depth(a, n=0):

    if isiterable(a):
        return get_depth(a[0], n+1)

    else:
        return n
```

Because, when `a` have more depth, you will calculate the `get_depth` function again witn `n+1` which is already count the depth correctly and the extras are not needed.

Btw, you have to think about what if this case?

```
d = [1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

I can modify a bit such as:

```
def get_depth(a, n=0):

    if isiterable(a):
        temp = []
        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            temp.append(get_depth(a[i], n+1))

        return max(temp)

    else:
        return n
```